# How do I get a Link in Body of email from cell - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink

I have spent 3 days on this particular query so would appreciate any help.
I have created a macro that sends an email to a particular person 30 days before a date in a spreadsheet, puts the title of the document in the Subject and marks up my spreadsheet to mark as email sent. Works perfectly!!! However I would like to put a link into the email from  a link that is in the spreadsheet so email recipient can just click on the link and they go straight to the document for review. Im trying to use the href and HTMLBody functions but with no luck, just a lot of hair pulling. If anyone could give me any help it would be wonderful. I have attached the code I am using. As I say works great up until the point I have used strbody. I just can;t figure out what I am doing wrong here. Many thanks

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, mymail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim datetoday1 As Date
Dim datetoday2 As Long
Dim strbody As String

Dim x As Long

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow

mydate1 = Cells(x, 8).Value
mydate2 = mydate1

Cells(x, 11).Value = mydate2
datetoday1 = Date
datetoday2 = datetoday1

Cells(x, 12).Value = datetoday2

If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 30 Then


Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olmailitem)

strbody = "Good Morning" & vbCrLf & _
     "Please be aware that this file is due for review in the next 30 days" & vbCrLf & _
     "Please click "<a href= Cells,(x, 13)" >here</ a>" &vbCrLF & _
     "Regards" & vbCrLf & _
     "Master Control Document"

      

mymail.To = Cells(x, 7).Value


With mymail
   .Subject = "Review Reminder " & Cells(x, 4).Value
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & strbody

   
   
   
   .Display
'.send
End With
Set myApp = Nothing
Set mymail = Nothing



Cells(x, 9) = "Yes"
Cells(x, 9).Font.ColorIndex = 3
Cells(x, 9).Font.Bold = True

Cells(x, 10).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2

End If
Next
Set myApp = Nothing
Set mymail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA, but shouldn't the following line be more like this: 

`"Please click <a href=""" & Cells,(x, 13) & """ >here</ a>" & vbCrLF & _`

Comment: You might just be missing the proper double-quote string:  `"Please click ""<a href= Cells,(x, 13)"" >here</ a>"`

Comment: Many thanks to you both!!!! I now have the output I desire...and yes, it was my quotation marks that were the issue. I really appreciate both your answers. All the very best. You've made my day (how very sad! :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code deals with an HTML document which represents the message body:

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & strbody
```

You need to insert your string between opening `<body>` and closing `</body>` tags if you want to add something to the existing message body.

Also the following string was not well formed for the HTML markup:

```
strbody = "Good Morning" & vbCrLf & _
     "Please be aware that this file is due for review in the next 30 days" & vbCrLf & _
     "Please click <a href=" & Cells,(x, 13) & " >here</ a>" & vbCrLF & _
     "Regards" & vbCrLf & _
     "Master Control Document"
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene; the quotation marks worked well for me. Which part was not well formed so I can gain some insight?

Comment: Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: It is, thank you,  but can't see how to mark it as resolved?

Comment: There should be a button if you are the post owner.

Comment: No, only things there are are the up and down vote button which I cant use as I'm the poster